# Is learning many different programming languages bad?

Tags: programming-languages

If someone asks you to make a program about something, can you do it in any languages that you know without looking into references?

Can you remember all the languages features, because there are features that are not possible in a language that are possible in other languages?
For instance, C++ can inherit two classes, and in Java you can't (interface you can). Also you can't initialize an instance variable in C++ if it's not a static const... in Java you can.

I ask this because before I can program in Visual Basic, but now that I'm studying Java, things change - as simple as the syntax for instantiating an object, and I get confused. I need to look at Visual Basic reference just to do it.

Is learning many different programming languages bad? Because I feel that I waste my time learning Visual Basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am mainly C# programmer, but I aslo know VB, Perl, C++, PHP and a bit of java. If I have a problem I can usually solve it in C# and VB without looking into references (of course depending on its complexity). I can also do it in other languages, but often I have to check the language docs (even if I have already done it 1000 times).

I do not think it's bad. Just  the opposite - it's good. But remember, that you will never be very good at all of them.

Comment: is C# and VB almost the same because they are both .net

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure it depends on the individual, but I would guess that for most people, learning more than one language is a good thing - in the same way that visiting other countries and trying new foods is a good thing: It broadens ones horizons and perhaps changes and challenges in the process.

When there are programming books out there like [seven-languages-in-seven-weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks) I think it's fairly safe to say that being a software polyglot is generally considered good, rather than bad.

Comment: how about memorizing the syntax can you memorize all that syntax?

Comment: I tend to use IDE's with intellisense tbh. For me personally, I don't mind having to use reference materials for the details, as long as I have understood the concept. More languages tends to equal more exposure to concepts - a downside (?) of that is exposure to different syntax which can cause a mental muddle!

Comment: +1, Seven Languages in Seven Weeks is a great book, esp. for OOP practitioners who want to expand their paradigm

Answer (score 3):

Learning different programming language *paradigms* is important and useful: The functional programming style is a very different way of solving problems, compared to OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Is learning many different spoken languages bad? The answer is no to both questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that learning many different programming languages is bad.

The problem you seem to be having is that you are studying two similar languages: Java and VB. The smae issue appears when one studies common (not programming) spoken languages. It's not good to be studying Italian and Spanish at the same time because the languages have differences but are so similar in many aspects that the mind gets confused and associates concepts/structures/grammar/words from one language with the other one.